# Using ggplot to create a professional looking graph

Tags: r

I have tried to use ggplot2 to create a professional-looking graph, but I have having some trouble with a lot of things. I would like to add color to the data points, add dates on the x-axis, and create a line of best fit or something similar if possible. I have been searching on Stack Exchange and Google in general to try and solve this problem but to no avail. I am using the "Civilian Labor Force Participation Rate: 20 years and over, Black or African American Men" from the Federal Reserve Bank of St. Louis (FRED).

I am using RStudio, and I imported the data from [LNS11300031](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/LNS11300031) and then used the `read.csv()` function to read it into `RStudio`. I initially used the `plot()` function to plot the data, but I want to use the `ggplot()` function to create a better looking graph, but when I create the graph the data points look very opaque, blurry, and cloudy, and there is no labels on the x-axis. I would like to add color and a line of best fit, but I do not know how to do that.

This is the code I used to create the graph with no x-axis labels:

```
ggplot(data = labor, mapping = aes(x = labor$DATE, y = labor$LNS11300031)) + geom_point(alpha = 0.1)
```

This is the graph that my code produced:

[image]

Here is some sample data (labor is the variable I used to store the data from the [FRED](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/LNS11300031) site):

```
head(labor)    DATE        LNS11300031
  1         1972-01-01        77.6
  2         1972-02-01        78.3
  3         1972-03-01        78.7
  4         1972-04-01        78.6
  5         1972-05-01        78.7
  6         1972-06-01        79.4
```

I would like to change the variable name `LNS11300031` to Labor Force Participation Rate

Additional information about the data:

```
str(labor)
'data.frame':   566 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ DATE       : Factor w/ 566 levels "1972-01-01","1972-02-01",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ LNS11300031: num  77.6 78.3 78.7 78.6 78.7 79.4 78.8 78.7 78.6 78.1 ...
```

I would like the code to create much clearer data points with color and a trend line, and be able to have an x-axis with the corresponding dates.

Comment: "How do I make by plot look nice" is pretty broad, and you might be better off starting with something like [ggpubr](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/) which has some nice defaults for the appearance. That said, your requirements are pretty specific so I think this question should be answerable.

Comment: Two other brief comments: your points look blurry because you made them blurry with `alpha = 0.1`! Make sure that option is doing what you want it to. And you do have x axis labels, it's just that you have so many they're all blending into an unreadable mess.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a basic attempt to cover all 3 of your desired improvements:

- Clearer points: don't set the alpha too low! A bit of alpha is good for overlapping points, but `alpha = 0.1` makes them too blurry.
- Colour: R understands simple colour names like "red", but also hex colour codes. Pick any colours you want.
- Trend line: easy to add with `stat_smooth()`. I've used `method='lm'` which gives a straight linear regression line but there are more flexible alternatives.
- Date labels on the x-axis: Make sure your `DATE` column is correctly set as a `Date` type, and use `scale_x_date()` to tweak the labels.

```
quantmod::getSymbols("LNS11300031", src="FRED")
# Your data is available from the quantmod package

labor = LNS11300031 %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    rownames_to_column(var = "DATE") %>%
    # Make sure DATE is a Date column
    mutate(DATE = as.Date(DATE))

# Generally, you don't use data$column syntax within ggplot, 
#   just give the column name
ggplot(data = labor, mapping = aes(x = DATE, y = LNS11300031)) + 
    geom_point(alpha = 0.7, colour = "#B07AA1") +
    stat_smooth(method = "lm", colour = "#E15759", se = FALSE) +
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = "5 years", date_labels = "%Y") +
    theme_minimal()
```

Output:

[image: Plot]

Comment: Thank you so much Marius, I really appreciate your prompt help, you completely answered my question as well as added information that I was not aware of but am very glad you included, and added the explanation that I needed to understand what I need to do moving forward. Thanks again!!!

Comment: Would there be any way I could add the African American Labor Force Participation Rate for women as well? I used the same quantmod package as you did, quantmod::getSymbols("LNU01300032", src="FRED")                                              and then I created a new variable labor2 with as the exact same as you did for the labor variable, and I just replaced  the LNS11300031 with the LNU01300032, but now I am not sure how to add both of the plots to the graph, while using the ggplot.

Comment: @pierrefrancois Yes, one way would be to add another geom_point and stat_smooth to the existing graph, and set "data = labor2" in the new geoms.